# How do i extract text from email body using UiPath?

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-robot, uipath-activity

I would like to know how do I extract the password form the email body. The password is used to open files in the attachment.
How should I approach this? Do I extract the password and store it in an excel file or is there a better way to open the file and store the data.

Below is an example email

```
Example email
From: ABC <abc@outlook.com>
Sent: Monday, 5 October 2020 10:54 AM
To: BCD <bcd@outlook.com>
Subject: Files
```

[image: Attached files]

The password is: ABCDE

Comment: Welcome to SO. I have no idea what you mean. Could you explain what you mean with password form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the password is always 5 characters long, you could get the email body and split it like this:

```
split(emailBody, "The password is:", 5)
```

[image]

[image]

You could then store the output in a variable to be used when opening the excel file.

Answer (score 1):

Just request the mails, once you have the MailMessage object use the method 'body' to access to it as a string.
Then you could capture the password with RegEx or other approach

Answer (score -1):

There may be different passwords to open the encrypted files and login to email. So there should be passwords for each encrypted file. You can store them in any way.